# How do I uninstall Java 1.6 from my Mac?

Tags: java, macos

I just got a Mac so I am struggling with the basics. Initially I installed Java 1.6 to my Mac - Yosemite OS. Then I installed the latest 1.8 version. When I do a java -version from the command line it still says 1.6. How do I get rid of 1.6 completely? Being a new Mac user I don't even know where Java is installed on my machine or how to remove programs from my computer. Can anyone help?

Comment: [Does this help?](http://superuser.com/questions/564687/how-do-i-uninstall-java6-from-mac-os-x)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue. I modified the [instructions I found at Macworld](http://www.macworld.com/article/2028900/how-to-disable-java-on-your-mac.html#tk.nl_mwbest) and set aside *some* of Apple's Java installation.

Since I wasn't comfortable flat out deleting components of Apple's Java installation, I made a directory on my desktop:

```
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/java-old/System/Library
```

Then, I moved the JVMs and other components out of the way

```
sudo mv /System/Library/Java ~/Desktop/java-old/System/Library
```

From there, I verified a new installation of Java 1.8. (nb: This was just j2se, not the full JDK). One other note, you'll still likely have parts of the Apple installed Java at /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework and at /usr/bin/java. I have not evaluated the safety of removing or altering the contents of those directories.